# Range Of Quartic Polynomial Of Two Variables

Tags: inequality, optimization

$a$,$b$ are real numbers such that $~3\leq a^{2}+ab+b^{2}\leq 6$.

I would like to find the range of $~a^{4}+b^{4}$.
Is it possible to find it with (well-known) AM-GM, CS, etc...?

Comment: Have you tried any of those? What happened?

Comment: @MatthewConroy/I've tried many times but failed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ab \le \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \implies \dfrac{3(a^2+b^2)}{2} \ge 3 \implies a^2+b^2 \ge2 \implies a^4+b^4 \ge 2(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2})^2 \ge 2 $  when $a=b=1$ hold "="

$a^4+b^4=(a^2+b^2+\sqrt{2}ab)(a^2+b^2-\sqrt{2}ab)=(u+(\sqrt{2}-1)ab)(u-(\sqrt{2}+1)ab)=u^2-2abu-a^2b^2, u=a^2+ab+b^2 \le 6$

it hints that when $ab<0$, the max will be got. let $c=-b>0, 3\le a^2-ac+c^2\le6  \implies ac \le6 $   when $a=c=\sqrt{6}$ hold "="

$a^4+b^4 \le 36+12ac-(ac)^2=72-(6-ac)^2\le 72$,when $a=c=-b=\sqrt{6}$ get "="

so  we get : $2\le a^4+b^4 \le 72$